# How to send file + JSON in single request from react to nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, fetch

I'm working on my personal ecommerce project where in seller page I'm adding product information such as Name, Category, description, price and image. I want to send this all data to backend to express server and store into postgresql. If any idea how to send image file and other text type data in single request please do tell.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Please use **FormData** to post the data as shown in the example below

```
const images = document.getElementById('imageControl');
const name = document.getElementById('nameControl');
const category = document.getElementById('categoryControl');
const description = document.getElementById('descriptionControl');
const price = document.getElementById('priceControl');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Name", name);
formData.append("Category", category);
formData.append("Description", description);
formData.append("Price", price);
formData.append("Image", images.files[0]);
const response = await fetch('url', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  body: formData
});
```